# MacOS Sierra all ports in use?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to run webpack-dev-server and no matter what port I use I get `EADDRINUSE`. If I `lsof` nothing appears to be using the port.

Any Idea what the issue could be here? Is there some sort of configuration necessary to host things locally on a mac? ..I have this working on both CentOS and Windows 7 without issue.

```
Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:4040/
webpack output is served from /    
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:4040
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

OSXDT8BDY3Hs-Mac-mini:cell-feature-search brandon$ lsof -Pn -i4
COMMAND    PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
UserEvent  294 brandon    4u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9275acf      0t0  UDP *:*
identitys  314 brandon   20u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9274eef      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd   331 brandon    4u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9f5e60f      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd   331 brandon    8u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9f5d30f      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd   331 brandon    9u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9f5eacf      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd   331 brandon   10u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9f5ce4f      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd   331 brandon   11u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9f5f1ef      0t0  UDP *:*
SystemUIS  730 brandon   11u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f927644f      0t0  UDP *:*
SystemUIS  730 brandon   12u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9274a2f      0t0  UDP *:*
SystemUIS  730 brandon   15u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f927456f      0t0  UDP *:62631
SystemUIS  730 brandon   16u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f927702f      0t0  UDP *:*
SystemUIS  730 brandon   18u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ebc8fe6f      0t0  UDP *:*
Finder     731 brandon   17u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ebc8b26f      0t0  UDP *:*
WiFiProxy  750 brandon    5u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ebc9032f      0t0  UDP *:*
WiFiAgent  797 brandon    5u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9275d2f      0t0  UDP *:*
eapolclie  890 brandon    3u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f9f5c72f      0t0  UDP *:*
ARDAgent  1245 brandon    8u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ebc8f02f      0t0  UDP *:3283
Google    2139 brandon   60u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ebc8fc0f      0t0  UDP *:*
Google    2139 brandon  121u  IPv4 0x30b113a2edad67e7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:50991->151.101.65.69:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  125u  IPv4 0x30b113a2eeec89d7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51219->63.251.109.83:443 (CLOSED)
Google    2139 brandon  129u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ef0202cf      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51220->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  130u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f85847e7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:50944->10.128.200.65:8009 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  144u  IPv4 0x30b113a2edad79d7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:50994->23.44.160.143:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  148u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ed2f7bc7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:50997->23.44.160.143:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  150u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ed2e5db7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:50996->54.225.188.155:443 (CLOSED)
Google    2139 brandon  156u  IPv4 0x30b113a2eeec9bc7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51187->12.129.210.52:443 (CLOSED)
Google    2139 brandon  169u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ef0ca0df      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51180->54.209.13.204:443 (CLOSED)
Google    2139 brandon  174u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ed2652cf      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51000->104.125.212.239:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  182u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ec77c2cf      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51006->104.16.2.9:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  183u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ed2f57e7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51008->23.44.160.11:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  185u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ec77cbc7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51009->23.44.160.11:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  187u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ef0cbbc7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51068->172.217.3.206:80 (CLOSED)
Google    2139 brandon  188u  IPv4 0x30b113a2eeeb6bc7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51069->173.194.56.244:80 (CLOSED)
Google    2139 brandon  190u  IPv4 0x30b113a2eeeb59d7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51016->74.121.133.33:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  193u  IPv4 0x30b113a2eeeb47e7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51070->173.194.56.119:80 (CLOSED)
Google    2139 brandon  197u  IPv4 0x30b113a2f7aa8db7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51149->104.16.112.18:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    2139 brandon  215u  IPv4 0x30b113a2ed2e27e7      0t0  TCP 10.128.202.154:51091->23.21.52.164:443 (CLOSED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of thoughts, but they are only educated guesses. Try changing the IP address to something else. With the odd security steps Mac OS likes to take, it could make a difference to set it to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0

Your lsof command is looking at IPv4 only, check IPv6 connections as well. I believe Mac OS X has the ss command:

```
ss -l src :4040
```

Last thing I have is to try is see what happens when you attempt to telnet into that port. A response of any kind tells you there is something listening, but hopefully it responds with more clues.

Comment: I've attempted using both 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 in addition to a mess of random ports. I also checked IPv6 and nothing there was using the host/port combo either.

I have to admit this is one of the stranger issues I've run into.

Answer (score 0):

The "address" that's in use is probably the port number, not the IPv4 address. And it's probably in use by root or by another user. You forgot to `sudo` your `lsof` so it's only showing you your own processes. Maybe you or launchd or something launched `webpack-dev-server` as `root` or `nobody` or `_www` or some other real user or system account, so now there's a copy running that you're not seeing, and it's keeping a listener open on *:4040/TCP.